# Extracting IIS Configuration in C++

Tags: c++, iis

I need to extract IIS Configuration into text files to finally compare those files (using WinDiff) 
to make sure that I have the same configuration on every server we have ( there are too many of them - we offer on demand services ).
In that purpose, I'm looking for a way to extract / dump IIS Configuration through a C++ program. 
I've already tried to read "applicationHost" XML file, but we can't do so. 
If somebody have already done that kind of things thanks for helping.
I've seen that there is an API given but the MSDN documentation is not that clear for me.
Thanks.